# Is refusal to renew passport sufficient for applying as a stateless person in Switzerland

Tags: working-visas, schengen, switzerland, stateless

I have a work permit in Switzerland. And it is valid until the end of my passport validity (within another 3 years).

My passport is going to expire after 3 years. I can't renew my passport until 2 years more from my embassy. That is because males can't renew their passports, from my embassy, until the final exemption from the military service which will be after 2 years (5 years from now) for me.

In my country, upon reaching a certain age, they are calling you to the military not because it is needed to or we are at war, but because you reached a certain age.

I have a question:

Is that a valid reason to apply for Switzerland travel foreign document as a stateless person? Just until being able to renew my passport again.

Comment: The term ‘stateless person’ means a person who is not considered as a national by any State under the operation of its law. Merely having an expired passport that you intend to renew doesn’t seem to me to fit that definition or to be grounds to be recognised as stateless https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/asyl/asylverfahren/weitere_themen/staatenlosigkeit.html#tab__content_sem_en_home_asyl_asylverfahren_weitere_themen_staatenlosigkeit_jcr_content_par_tabctrl_0

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer.

Comment: What can be done to stay legally there and continue working? I would need a foreign travel document or something.

Comment: You cannot assume there is a solution that does not involve going back to your country of citizenship and completing your military service. Until you get another citizenship, you still depend on that country to some extent. There are special cases (including refugees) but the laws are not designed to escape that basic reality.

Comment: I have the feeling you're still trying to deny the problem you're facing, perhaps even to yourself and it sends you on all sorts of wild goose chases. You don't need to renew your residence permit without a passport, you're not stateless, and being able to continue working is not your main problem. You're trying to avoid the draft in your country. That's where you should start to find out if there are legal solutions to do it or whether other people have managed it.

Comment: You *are* able to get your passport renewed, all you need to do is to comply with your country's laws. That's not an unheard of demand, in fact many countries condition their passports' issuance/renewal on being up to date with compliance requirements.

Comment: If you lose your passport, you could apply for a replacement.  If you got lucky you could ask for it to be a new issue.  Unless you are of the age for compulsory service you might be able to renew your passport early and it would extend past the end of your compulsory service age.  This won't work if you are already in the compulsory service age though.

Comment: If you had permanent resident status in a country, then typically you don't need to have a passport to maintain status indefinitely. For example, if you are a green card holder living in the US, you don't need to have a passport to stay in the US or renew your green card (or, even, to enter the US). I am not familiar with Swiss immigration statuses, but it sounds like this "work permit" you are talking about is not a permanent resident status, and they require you to have a valid passport to make sure there is a place to send you back to at the end of your stay.

Comment: @Relaxed Similar to how the "sovereign citizen" movement often starts by simply trying to deny the fact that you haven't paid your traffic tickets and are no longer allowed to drive, so you need to invent "right to travel" and such. Inventing a whole fictional legal system won't save you from reality.

Comment: Just wanted to also comment that a passport does not equal citizenship. It is a document of identity, and it may indeed state that you are a citizen of the country that issued you the passport. But it does not itself actually *confer* citizenship or have an affect on it. Any sovereign nation has the right to deny a citizen a passport, especially if they fail to meet certain conditions such as following the laws of that nation. (There are ofcourse considerations for [UDHR - Article 13](https://www.un.org/en/about-us/universal-declaration-of-human-rights).)

Comment: @user102008 There is a no obvious connection between the status and the requirement to hold a passport in Europe. In France it's possible to reside lawfully without a passport with any residence permit (*carte de séjour*) and that's the only document the authorities really care about. In Germany a passport is required even for holders of a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*.

Answer (score 12):

That's not possible because you are not stateless. You could presumably easily return to your country and serve in the military if you wanted to, that's pretty much the opposite of statelessness.

You keep saying that you cannot renew your passport but that's not quite the problem here, at least from the perspective of the authorities. The fact is that you're trying to avoid conscription and governments do not necessarily want to make that easy, even for foreign citizens.

In the EU, being called for military service can be grounds for subsidiary protection but only if you are fleeing military draft in a country that is at war, you can show that you would be forced to commit war crimes or face unreasonably harsh punishment. It's not the case if you merely find military service inconvenient.

Also note that Switzerland (which is not in the EU) is a country with a strong tradition of mandatory service in the military. All Swiss men have to serve for several months of mandatory training when they turn 18, get a service weapon, and then go back every year or every other year for a few days until they turn 40 or so. If you get an exemption (even on medical grounds), you have to pay a special 3% income tax, which Swiss people frequently describe as a way to contribute to the defense of the country in another way.

Military service is therefore much more important there than in neighbouring countries like France or Germany. Culturally, I would not expect much understanding of your wish to avoid service from Swiss citizens.